# C# method for converting CSV to sparse data format for libsvm

Tags: c#, machine-learning, libsvm

I have developed a C# method for converting CSV to [sparse data](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#_TOP) format. The code works nice but sometimes it fells. So, does anybody 
have a C# method for converting CSV file to sparse file.

The format of sparse data is

[label] [column_index]:[value] [column_index]:[value] ...

[label] [column_index]:[value] [column_index]:[value] ...

One thing is that whenever a column value is 0 the column_index is jumped. 
For example,

400,0.39,0,0.098,0.4387

421,0.63,0.23,0,0.14

represented as

400 1:0.39 3:0.098 4:0.4387

421 1:0.63 2:0.23 4:0.14

My C# code was:

```
public static string getSparse(string path)
    {
        string final_string = String.Empty;

        string[] line = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

        int count = 0, m = 0;

        foreach (string ln in line)
        {
            string[] num = ln.Split(new char[] { ',' });

            foreach (string n in num)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                    final_string += n + " ";
                else
                {
                    if (n == "0")
                    {
                        count++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    final_string += count + ":" + n + " ";
                }
                count++;
            }

            count = 0;

            final_string += Environment.NewLine;
            m++;
        }

        return final_string;
    }
```